# CSS place all content on bottom

Tags: html, css

At my website http://joeybabcock.me (Novice programmer:) yes I know the site works horrible. At the top you can see the green links. I have tried the the following CSS to make it stay on the bottom, and also using a div:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:left;    
vertical-align:bottom;
```

Comment: you probably want `position: fixed`.

Comment: Why not use a **footer** tag in HTML?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I tried that, didn't work either :(

Comment: You should separate the nav from the table, use a `div`, and then add `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: @ManofSnow That didn't work either...    albert-xing How might i do that?

Comment: Well it seems you have an answer below, it should work

Comment: I dont know why but it doesn't for some reason? anyone have a clue as to why?

Comment: Never mind i just pressed enter and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below style-sheet

```
footer {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1111;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to go through the rest of my css because its still not working:(